# Android database not updating

Tags: android, sqlite

This method is supposed to update the friend in the database. But it is not. No error is shown, tried restarting to refresh the list etc still nothing. Log is showing me new values but they are not saved in the database.

```
public void updateFriend(Friend friend) {
    Log.d("UpdateFriendMethod", friend.toString());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, friend.getName()); 
    values.put(KEY_BIRTHDAY, friend.getBirthday().getTimeInMillis());
    db.update(TABLE_Friends,
            values, 
            KEY_NAME + " = ?", 
            new String[] { String.valueOf(friend.getName()) });

    db.close();
}
```

Here is the way how do I get items from db:

```
public List<Friend> getAllFriends() {
    List<Friend> Friends = new LinkedList<Friend>();
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_Friends;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Friend friend = new Friend();
            friend.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            Date date = new Date(cursor.getLong(1));
            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.setTime(date);
            friend.setBirthday(cal);
            Friends.add(friend);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("getAllFriends()", Friends.toString());
    return Friends;
}
```

I bet, problem is somewhere in that SQL statement, I am not familiar with it yet, I am used to SQL language not this.

Comment: `friend.getName()` apparently returns the *new* name and using it in a `WHERE` condition won't match any rows. Use the `rowid` to refer to a particular row.

Comment: Good point but this is not an issue I guess, because I am not changing the name, just the birthday.

Comment: What is the value of `i` returned i.e. the number of rows affected? How are you getting the values from the database so you know they're not updated?

Comment: Check the edit please, i is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED, problem was in SQL statement as I later found out:

```
public void updateFriend(Friend friend) {
    Log.d("UpdateFriendMethod", friend.toString());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, friend.getName());
    values.put(KEY_BIRTHDAY, friend.getBirthday().getTimeInMillis());
    db.update(TABLE_Friends, values, KEY_NAME + "='" + friend.getName()
            + "'", null);
    db.close();

}
```